# Proving that for all $1 \leq k \leq p - 1$, $p$ prime, $\binom{p}{k} \equiv 0 \bmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I decided to prove by induction (though am running into some issues).

(Base case) When $k = 1$, we have
$$\binom{p}{1} = \frac{p!}{1! \cdot (p - 1)!} = p \equiv 0 \bmod p.$$
When $k = p - 1$, we have
$$\binom{p}{p - 1} = \frac{p!}{(p - 1)! \cdot (p - p + 1)!} = \frac{p!}{(p - 1)! \cdot 1!} = p \equiv 0 \bmod p.$$
(Inductive step) For some $1 < k < p - 1$, assume $\binom{p}{k} \equiv 0 \bmod p$. We will show that $\binom{p}{k + 1} \equiv 0 \bmod p$. By substitution, we obtain
$$\binom{p}{k + 1} = \frac{p!}{(k + 1)! \cdot (p - k - 1)!} = \frac{p!}{k!(p - k)!} \cdot \frac{p - k}{k + 1} = \binom{p}{k} \cdot \frac{p - k}{k + 1}$$
Since the inductive hypothesis assumes that $\binom{p}{k} \equiv 0 \bmod p \implies \binom{p}{k} \cdot a \equiv 0 \bmod p \ \forall \ a \in \mathbb{Z}$, I need to somehow show that $\frac{p - k}{k + 1}$ is an integer, but it doesn't seem like it always will be.

Ultimately, I think it may be easier to not use induction, but I think it *can* be done this way and I just want to see if anyone has a good idea on how to continue my logic.

Comment: It's not true that $\frac{p - k}{k  + 1} \in \mathbb{Z}$, but you know that $\binom{p}{k+1}$ is integer.

Comment: Note that $\binom{p}{k+1}=\binom{p}{k}\cdot\frac{p-k}{k+1}\;\;\to\;\;(k+1)\cdot\binom{p}{k+1}=\binom{p}{k}\cdot(p-k)$. Also, your base case of $\binom{p}{1} = \frac{p!}{1! \cdot p!} = 1 \equiv 0 \bmod p$ should be $\binom{p}{1} = \frac{p!}{1! \cdot \color{red}{(p-1)}!} = \color{red}{p} \equiv 0 \bmod p$ instead.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks! Is this enough to prove the inductive step? Since this equation is not explicitly saying that $\binom{p}{k} \equiv 0 \bmod p$? Or is the next step to show that $(k + 1)$ has an inverse mod $p$ so $(k + 1) \cdot \binom{p}{k + 1} = \binom{p}{k} \cdot (p - k) \implies (k + 1) \cdot \binom{p}{k + 1} \equiv 0 \bmod p \implies \binom{p}{k + 1} \equiv 0 \cdot (k + 1)^{-1} \equiv 0 \bmod p$?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you could show $k+1$ has an inverse. However, an alternative is that since $p\mid\binom{p}{k}\;\to\;p\mid\binom{p}{k}\cdot(p-k)$, then $p\mid(k+1)\cdot\binom{p}{k+1}$. Thus, because $1\le k \lt p-1 \;\;\to\;\;2\le k+1\lt p$, then $p\nmid k+1$, so $p\mid\binom{p}{k+1}$. Also, in case you weren't aware, there's quite a few posts here which solve the problem without induction, e.g., [Why is $ {n\choose k} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ if $n$ is prime?](/q/1296999).

Comment: The base case is clearly wrong.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Oops, sorry about that. I should be keener on looking for existing help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that, for $p$ prime, to prove

$$\binom{p}{k}\equiv 0\bmod{p}\;\;\forall\;\;1\le k\le p-1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

it's generally easier to not use induction (e.g., such as shown in [Why is $ {n\choose k} \equiv 0 \pmod n$ if $n$ is prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1296999)). Nonetheless, you've made a good start with using induction, although there are several issues:

1. It's unnecessary to include a base case of $k=p-1$. This is because that's already handled in the inductive step where, with $k=p-2$, it's shown that $k+1=p-1$ also satisfies \eqref{eq1A}.
2. With the inductive step, you wrote "For some $1 < k < p - 1$ ...". However, the inequality should be $1\color{red}{\le}k\lt p-1$ instead, to have the induction start from your base case of $k=1$.
3. From your result of
   $$\binom{p}{k + 1} = \binom{p}{k}\cdot\frac{p - k}{k + 1} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
   you can't "... somehow show that $\frac{p - k}{k + 1}$ is an integer ..." because it's not true in general, as [openspace's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653558/proving-that-for-all-1-leq-k-leq-p-1-p-prime-binompk-equiv-0-b#comment9827013_4653558) indicates.

When checking divisibility, it's generally easier to deal with products of just integers rather than with one or more non-integral rational numbers. As such, by multiplying both sides of \eqref{eq2A} by $k+1$, we get

$$(k+1)\cdot\binom{p}{k + 1} = \binom{p}{k}\cdot(p - k) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Note that $1\le k\lt p-1 \;\;\to\;\;2\le k+1 \lt p$, so $p\nmid k+1$. Thus, as you indicated in your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4653558/proving-that-for-all-1-leq-k-leq-p-1-p-prime-binompk-equiv-0-b#comment9827048_4653558), we could state that $k+1$ has a multiplicative inverse modulo $p$ to get that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& (k+1)\cdot\binom{p}{k + 1} = \binom{p}{k}\cdot(p - k) \implies (k+1)\cdot\binom{p}{k + 1}\equiv 0\bmod{p} \\
& \implies \binom{p}{k + 1}\equiv 0\cdot(k+1)^{-1}\equiv 0\bmod{p}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Alternatively, from \eqref{eq3A}, since $p\mid\binom{p}{k}\;\;\to\;\;p\mid(k+1)\cdot\binom{p}{k + 1}$, but $p\nmid k+1$, then

$$p\mid\binom{p}{k + 1}\;\;\to\;\;\binom{p}{k + 1}\equiv 0\bmod{p}\tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

With either \eqref{eq4A} or \eqref{eq5A}, the inductive step is completed and, thus, \eqref{eq1A} has been proven to be true.

Comment: Great answer, John. I understand now. Thanks for all your help.